# Code coverage in Azure DevOps also calculates external packages

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, code-coverage

Inside an Azure DevOps pipeline I've set up code coverage using next YML code:

```yaml
- stage: Test_application
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'DotNet Test'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        arguments: '--configuration Release --collect "Code coverage"'
        projects: '**/MyLibrary.UnitTest.*.csproj'
```

But when I look at the results, It seems that it includes also the packages `diffengine.dll`, `moq.dll` and `shouldly.dll`. What brings the code coverage to 9.82%.

[image]

But These packages are downloaded from NuGet and must be excluded from the results. The result must be *(in my opinion)* 31.61%. Only taking `MyLibrary.One.dll`, `MyLibrary.Two.dll`, `MyLibrary.Tree.dll`
and `MyLibrary.Four.dll`.

How could I filter only these `dll`s?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a runsettings file like this one in the repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>YOUR_DLL_NAME_HERE.dll</ModulePath>
              </Include>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

And then in the pipeline use it

```
- stage: Test_application
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'DotNet Test'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        arguments: '--configuration Release --collect "Code coverage" --settings:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\codecoverage.runsettings'
        projects: '**/MyLibrary.UnitTest.*.csproj'
```